# OpenGL surface changes in Qt 5.7. Incorrect drawing textures with alpha channel

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5.7

I'm use same code with Qt 5.5

```
class MyGlWidget : public QOpenGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyGlWidget(QWidget* parent = 0);
    virtual ~MyGlWidget();

protected:
    virtual void initializeGL()
    {
        QOpenGLContext* context = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();

        QSurfaceFormat format = context->format();
        format.setVersion(2,1);
        context->setFormat(format);

        ...
    }

    virtual void paintGL() { ... }
```

And in that case "format" is:

```
QSurfaceFormat(version 2.1, options QFlags(0x4), depthBufferSize 24,
redBufferSize 8, greenBufferSize 8, blueBufferSize 8, alphaBufferSize 8, 
stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  2)
```

But in Qt 5.7 "format" is:

```
QSurfaceFormat(version 2.1, options QFlags(0x4), depthBufferSize -1,
redBufferSize 8, greenBufferSize 8, blueBufferSize 8, alphaBufferSize -1,
stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0)
```

So, textures with alpha channel draws incorrectly.
I tried to set format with right params manually, but it doesn't take effect.

Comment: You can't change the format of an already created context. Use `QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat` before creating the widget instead.

Comment: I tried to set QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat, buy alpha channel still draws incorrectly